# Post comment and then display the comments using ajax and jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am developing an asp.net application in which I want to implement the discussion panel. I am able to post and display problem now I want to post comments on the problem. My requirement is when I click on the submit button of comment box then the comment will display and the comment box will be slide down similar to Stackoverflow comments. I know this is possible by using jquery and ajax but how? I don't know.

Comment: There you go : http://tutorialzine.com/2010/06/simple-ajax-commenting-system/ it uses php but should be easy to convert into asp .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="commentTag">Comments</div>
<div id="txtArea">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

and the jquery part

```
$("#commentTag").on("click",function(){

    $("#txtArea").slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bVhzj/1/