# Adding Comment with AJAX POST and displaying it in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have just started to learn ajax. I am implementing it in my Django project where every Discussion (Model) has Comment (Model). I have designed such that the page refreshes after every comment is made. But I don't want to do that, so use AJAX for the same.

views.py :

```
def single_discuss(request, slug):
    discussion = get_object_or_404(Discussion, slug=slug)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(discussion=discussion)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == "POST":
            comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                comment_form = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                comment_form.commenter = request.user
                comment_form.discussion = discussion
                comment_form.save()
                return redirect('single_discuss', slug=discussion.slug)
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    else:
        comment_form = None
    return render(request, 'single_discuss.html',
                  {'discuss': discussion, 'comments': comments,
                   'comment_form': comment_form})
```

single_discuss.html :

```
<div class="single-comment">
        <form class="form-inline" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ comment_form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Comment!</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

How do I this? I am trying to learn AJAX, so please tell me where should I add what and why? Thanks in advance.

I tried understanding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864834/posting-comment-with-ajax-and-jquery?rq=1) which said something else, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008564/post-comment-and-then-display-the-comments-using-ajax-and-jquery) I don't even think answers completely even though it is marked correct.

Comment: Did you write any javascript code for AJAX. it is not posted in question?

Comment: Check jQuery's ajax() method